# PHP echo json is always blank value

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to return some values as JSON from mysql database with PHP.

I've tried many ways and I think my code is correct, but it always return blank.

This way I can see returned values:

```
echo $row['name'];
```

But when I use

> json_encode

it returns blank.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// $dbconfig = require_once('../config.php');
require_once('../DBConnection.php');

// $database = new DBConnection($dbconfig);
// $sqlSelect = "select * from Estados";
// $rows = $database->getQuery($sqlSelect);

$response = array();

class EstadoDAO {

    public function getEstados($dbconfig) {

        $sqlSelect = "select * from Estados";
        $database = new DBConnection($dbconfig);

        try {
            $rows = $database->getQuery($sqlSelect);
            if ($rows) {
                $response["estado"] = array();
                foreach($rows as $row){
                    //echo $row['name']; // IT WORKS
                    $estado = array();
                    $estado['name'] = $row['name'];

                    array_push($response["estado"], $estado);
                }
            } else {
                //zero linhas
                $estado = array();
                $estado['name'] = $row['ERRO'];

                array_push($response["estado"], $estado);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }

        $database->__destruct();
        echo json_encode($response);
    } //function
}// Class
```

**EDIT 1**

var_dump response:

```
array(1) { ["estado"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Rio Grande do Sul" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Santa Catarina" } [2]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Paran�" } } }
```

Comment: `$response` does not exist within your scope until you create it if $rows exists. Move your definition out of the top of the file and into your function.

Comment: Also, your else will throw errors if there are no rows, since neither `$row` nor `$response` will exist.

Comment: @aynber inside the function it continues returning blank.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($response);` before or after your json_encode, and let us know what it says. You might also want to actually show an error in your catch block while you're testing, so you can see if it's hitting that block.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @aynber edited.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm using it.

Comment: use `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: It's probably because you have unescaped unicode in your records.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal nothing changed, still blank.

Comment: Can you show us how you create the db connection? I mean, PDO or similar connection? Perhaps you need to set the charset there?

Comment: You guided me to the right way, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was needed to use

> utf8_encode

Here is the answer:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    //echo $row['name']; // IT WORKS
    $estado = array();
    $estado['name'] = utf8_encode($row['name']);

    array_push($response["estado"], $estado);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have unescaped unicode in your records.

use `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php